# Как получить доступ к ViewModel родителя из ViewModel UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

У меня есть окно c `ContentContrоl` куда я помещаю `UserControl` .

```
<catel:Window.Resources>
    <catel:ViewModelToViewConverter x:Key="ToView"/>
</catel:Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MainView, Converter={StaticResource ToView}}"/>


</Grid>
```

Как мне обратится ко ViewModel окна из ViewModel  дочернего `UserControl`?

Comment: Через [ViewModelManager](http://docs.catelproject.com/5.2/introduction/mvvm/creating-view-models-with-catel/#viewmodelmanager)

Comment: Если ей нужна ссылка на корневую VM, то пусть она получает ее как зависимость хоть через конструктор, хоть через свойство, хоть параметром метода или команды. GUI тут вообще ни при чем.